# How to implement pause/resume feature for wav audio with sounddevice in python

Tags: python, wav, audio-player, python-sounddevice

I wanted to implement the pause/resume feature using sounddevice. I found out that this library doesn't have a dedicated method to achieve this as other libraries like PyGame. But for my specific case, PyGame didn't work since I was reading the audio data from a binary file `.atm`, which is just a made-up extension our professor forced us to use. But still applies.

So, how can you achieve this? First I use `scipy.io.wavfile` to read the `samplerate` and `data` like this.

```
samplerate, data = wavfile.read('audio.wav')
```

With sounddevice you can use `sd.play(data, samplerate)` to reproduce the audio file. And to pause and resume you can use this code:

```
import time
import sounddevice as sd

def toggle_playback():
    """Toggles audio playback between playing and paused states."""

    global playback_state, current_position, start_timestamp, accumulated_time

    if playback_state == "playing":
        sd.stop()
        end_timestamp = time.time()
        accumulated_time += end_timestamp - start_timestamp
        current_position = int(samplerate * accumulated_time)
        playback_state = "paused"
        play_pause_button.config(text="Resume")

    else:  # Audio is paused
        sd.play(data[current_position:], samplerate)
        start_timestamp = time.time()
        playback_state = "playing"

# ... (Rest of your code)
```

In my case I'm using tkinter with a simple interface, and I have a button that toggles resume and pause, but you can separate the `if statement` into two functions and call them as necessary.

Basically what I'm doing is tracking the time when the audio starts reproducing and when it ends. I subtract them to get the elapsed time and then calculate the index (`current_position`) of the array `data` by multiplying it by the samplerate. Which is the number of samples per second of the audio file. This array is probably huge, in my case a 16 sec audio has shape of (705600, 2). And then when hitting resume, I just pass the array from the the position `current_position` and forward.

Hope this can help someone!

I tried using other libraries, but only found PyGame and it doesn't accept two-dimensional arrays containing the audio data.